# ASP.net RegularExpressions

Tags: asp.net, validation

Ok so I have a regular expression validator on my form but I am new to it and was wondering how I add another expression to it so I can look for something else as well. Here is my sample code:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
     ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" 
     ControlToValidate="txtRelationship" 
     ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z''-,\'.'\s]{1,30}$"
     EnableClientScript="true"  
     Display="None" 
     ValidationGroup="<%# ((TSAPassenger)((RepeaterItem)Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem).PaxKey %>" 
     runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="Invalid Relationship.">
     Invalid Relationship
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I am trying to add in if the field name is equal to "test" or "tba" to give the same error or a different error. How would I add another expression into this?

---

Would the second validation look like this?

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtName" ValidationExpression="^.*\b(test|tba)\b.*$"
                                        EnableClientScript="true"  Display="None" ValidationGroup="<%# ((TSAPassenger)((RepeaterItem) Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem).PaxKey %>" runat="server" ErrorMessage="This can not be used as a Contact Name."></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorName" ControlToValidate="txtName" Enabled="<%# (Container.ItemIndex == 0 || Container. = "test") %>" ValidationGroup="<%# ((TSAPassenger)((RepeaterItem) Container.Parent.Parent).DataItem).PaxKey %>" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Contact Name is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Please provide more code.  What type of object are you using the ErrorMEssage property on?  Is this C#?  WHat's the code behind look like? etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be IMHO to use a custom validator and code your validations in the onServerValidate event.

Of course, you can always add another regExp validator or even a compare validator to the same object you are validating.

Hope this helps

Comment: So I can just add another one in this that is more on this expression to find test or tba and just give a different error message out?

Comment: Yes. A single input element can have multiple validators attached to it, each one with a different error message. Ensure to set the correct value of Display property in validators to suite your particular UI.